# Parallel approach for large batch processing involving a lot of disk I/O

Tags: database, algorithm, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, disk

I've got a task where I need to do the following

```
for fi in files, do in parallel:
  for job in jobs, do serially:
    read fi into memory from disk
    do job(fi), save output to disk
```

(Peculiarities of the task make it impractical to parallelize the inner loop.)

There are thousands of `files` and about 400 `jobs`.  Right now the `files` are a bunch of .csvs, and I'm saving the output to a bunch of csv's elsewhere.  input csvs are about 30MB, outputs are about 10MB

What I really want is a database, but the databases that I know about can't handle parallel I/O.  So I'm just reading from and saving a bunch of csv's.  I know that the OS can't do parallel I/O either, but it handles parallel requests better than the databases that I know about.

So, what's a better way to do this?  I'm on AWS, and right now everything is sitting in an EBS volume.  Would I expect better performance pushing all the inputs up to an S3 bucket, downloading them as needed, and uploading the outputs (the files are a couple of MB each)?

Or is there some sort of parallel I/O database architecture that lives on the cloud somewhere that I can learn about and then rent?

Suggestions for how to approach this are appreciated.

Comment: About how big is each file csv?

Comment: @displayName  Input CSVs are about 30MB.  Output ones are about 10MB. Question edited

Comment: How calculation intensive is `job(fi)`?

Comment: @displayName Fairly big.  I need to make sure that my instances have about 6 gigs of RAM per worker.

Comment: How often would this be repeated? Are you looking for a short term solution or a long term process?

Comment: I do this sort of thing a lot.  I've tried to use databases in the past, but they break when lots of workers are reading and writing from them.  So, I'm looking for a general way of reading/writing to a database in parallel.  Maybe I should focus on the general question, rather than the specific instance here.

Comment: "What I really want is a database, but the databases that I know about can't handle parallel I/O" - erm , which ones would those be?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing way more I/O than you need to. You have:

```
for fi in files, do in parallel:
  for job in jobs, do serially:
    read fi into memory from disk
    do job(fi), save output to disk
```

Assuming you have the ability to create a memory stream, you could do this:

```
for fi in files, do in parallel:
  read fi into memory and create memory stream ms
  for job in jobs, do serially:
    do job(ms), save output to disk
```

This assumes, of course, that you're making a copy of the file that you read in from disk, rather than modifying it in place.

That should increase your speed pretty substantially. Rather than reading thousands of files 400 times each, you read each file once.

Answer (score 0):

30MB is nothing for the modern systems. So I guess your bottleneck is the jobs, not the IO. You need to confirm the guess, but it looks like improving the IO is a waste of time.

What you might try to both reduce the file size and computation complexity is to simply use a custom binary format. The size of the files will be smaller, reading them will take less time since we don't need to convert strings to numbers and vice versa.

Just an idea...

Comment: While that is likely true, it sure would be convenient to have a database.

Comment: @generic_user then use it! Whatever SQL/noSQL database will handle 30MB. Do not waste your time looking for the parallel IO, since the difference will be negligible if any...

Answer (score 0):

Your `job` is computation intensive. So if you are already achieving 100% CPU usage, I doubt there can be an improvement by parallelizing the reads.

There are two things that can be done to improve your current solution:

1. Use SSDs to bring the I/O time to the bare minimum, if you are not already doing that;
2. Divide your task so that you can make use of more than one machine. If you have achieved 100% CPU usage and want to do still faster, you clearly need more cores to run you task on.